# kafka installed as a cloudera csd does not show up in service list

Tags: cloudera, apache-kafka, parcel

I added kafka as a new parcel using its csd

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/kafka/1-2-0.html

Everything worked up to downloading, distributing and activating the kafka parcel, but it does not show up as a service you can add to the cluster.

Does anyone have a successful experience with this?

Comment: I restarted a new cluster, this time indicating to include the kafka parcel. Yet the add services page still does not show kafka as a possible service to add. How do you do this?

Comment: I know this is way old topic, and Kafka is supported in the CDH5.4 and later out of the box.  For someone landed here from Google search, I had to restart the whole machine (CDH5.9 quickstart VM) to get the new services shown up in thee "Add Service" screen.  It's worth trying if the restart command doesn't work.  CDH is annoying piece of software until you find the stable configuration.  It doesn't tell you what went wrong.  It hides a lot of details.

Answer (score 0):

You must install csd correctly, specifically execute **step 3**: "service cloudera-scm-server restart". then Kafka will appear in 'add a service'.